# Partial template specialisation of a functor that's calling a member method of objects passed to it

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, function-pointers, partial-specialization

I have the following functor and its partial specialisation

```
template    <class _T, typename _Return = void, typename _Arg = void>
struct  Caller
{
    typedef _Return(_T::*Method)(_Arg);

    Caller(Method pm, _Arg a)
    :   _pMethod(pm),
        _arg(a)
    {}

    _Return operator()(_T& obj)
    {
        return (obj.*_pMethod)(_arg);
    }

    Method  _pMethod;
    _Arg    _arg;
};

template    <class _T, typename _Return>
struct  Caller<_T, _Return, void>
{
    typedef _Return(_T::*Method)();

    Caller(Method pm)
    :   _pMethod(pm)
    {}

    _Return operator()(_T& obj)
    {
        return (obj.*_pMethod)();
    }

    Method  _pMethod;
};
```

I'm trying to use it the following way:

```
struct Foo
{
    void Bar() const
    {
         void(0);
    }
};

// ...

std::list<Foo> foos;
const std::list<Foo> &rFoos(foos);
std::for_each(rFoos.begin(), rFoos.end(), Caller<const Foo>(&Foo::Bar));
```

I'm getting this, for the last line of code (the IDE picks up at the Caller):

> error C2440: '' : cannot convert from 'void
>   (__thiscall Foo::* )(void) const' to 'Caller<_T>'
>   1>          with
>   1> [
>   1>              _T=const Foo
>   1>          ]
>   1>          No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload
>   resolution was ambiguous

This code would work in a g++ environment. (If I `Caller<Foo>(&Foo::Bar)` g++ would complain, which makes sense, as the function will only be called on a **const** object).

I have tried various things, including adding `operator()(const _T& obj)` / `operator()(const _T& obj) const` varieties to the functor, but to no avail.

This would be accepted by the compiler:

```
struct Foo
{
    void Bar()
    {
         void(0);
    }
};

// ...

std::list<Foo> foos;
const std::list<Foo> &rFoos(foos);
std::for_each(rFoos.begin(), rFoos.end(), Caller<Foo>(&Foo::Bar));
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I make the functor template work for const member functions in Visual C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the constness of `_T` in `Caller` doesn't reflect in `this`'s
constness of `Method` automatically in MSVC
(If anything, I feel GCC's behaviour you mentioned is strange).
If you want to reflect the constness of `_T` in the constness of `this`,
how about preparing auxiliary class `Select_Type` like the following, and
selecting the proper signature according to the constness of `T_`?

```
template <class C, class T, class Const_T>
struct Select_Type { typedef T type; };

template <class C, class T, class Const_T>
struct Select_Type<C const, T, Const_T> { typedef Const_T type; };

template    <class _T, typename _Return>
struct  Caller<_T, _Return, void>
{
    typedef typename Select_Type<
        _T, _Return(_T::*)(), _Return(_T::*)()const >::type Method;
    ....
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `operator()` functions need to be const (they don't mutate the functor itself, but I don't believe you need a new set of functions).

Also note that all your types that start with underscore and a capital letter are reserved by the standard for the implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the point on naming standards - does that only apply to type names?

Comment: ...and thanks for the suggestion; tried it now - didn't work. I have now modified the question to better reflect the original problem. (Tested the suggestion with both snippets.)